# Cannot create javascript array from JSON response

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, arrays

I am using Jquery and AJAX to call a web method in my C# code behind, which runs a stored procedure and then sends the data back as a string. This is all working perfectly.

When I have my values back and I try make an array out of them so I can select only certain objects out of the array, everything falls apart. I have made a quick [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/emh3J/) of the problem I am having.

I receive a string like this from my Stored Procedure: `12, 1288, 1800, 3088, 26288`

But when I try get the "12" only, I either receive the whole string or just the "1" from the 12.

I have tried everything from `makeArray, stringify, split, replacing then splitting, making an array variable and push() into it`... nothing seems to work.

Below is some of my scrap code which I have been commenting out as I try and I've also added an image of the code behind while stepping through:

```
 $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      url: "LeadGraphGeneration.aspx/GetData",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      data: strRequest,
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function (msg) {
                          var returned = (msg.d);
                          //                          var returned = new Array();
                          //                          $(msg.d).each(function () {
                          //                              returned.push(this);
                          //                          });

                          ret1 = returned[1];

                          //                          var returnedd = JSON.stringify(msg.d);
                          //                          var returned = $.makeArray(returnedd);



                          //                          var ret1 = returned[0];
                          //                          var ret2 = returned[1];
                          //                          var ret3 = returned[2];
                          //                          var ret4 = returned[3];
                          //                          var ret5 = returned[4];


                          //data1 = dataArray[0];


                          $("#PaymentPeriod").text(ret1);
                          //                          $("#TotalInterest").text(ret2);
                          //                          $("#TotalFees").text(ret3);
                          //                          $("#TotalCost").text(ret4);
                          //                          $("#TotalPayment").text(ret5);
```

[image]
(Right click, open in new tab for full size)
I'm hoping you could help me figure out why I can't select individual objects from the array which I am struggling to build.

Please let me know if you need any more info.

Comment: try this `var rett = $.parseJSON("["+returnedd+"]");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "but when I try get the "12" only, I either receive the whole string or just the "1" from the 12.."

If your string is `"12, 1288, 1800, 3088, 26288"` and it's in `msg.d`, then:

```
var returned = msg.d.split(/\s*,\s*/);
```

The regular expression tells `split` to split the string on any run of optional whitespace characters followed by a comma followed by optional whitespace characters.

Comment: Thanks TJ... This worked! I will accept the answer as soon as I can. I need to go brush up on my Regex so i dont sit for hours trying to sort something out. haha

Answer (score 1):

```
var returnedd = "12, 1288, 1800, 3088, 26288"
var rett = $.makeArray(returnedd);
```

`makeArray` will not convert a string in that format to an array, rather use `split`:

```
var rett = returnedd.replace(/\s/g, "").split(",");
alert(rett[0])
```

As for

```
ret2 = returnedd[0];
```

This is calling `[0]` on a *string* which will give you the first *char* (just like `.charAt(0)`)